# Change Parameter Type in Linq to Sql concurrency check

Tags: linq-to-sql

I understand from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947(v=vs.110).aspx that Linq-to-Sql will convert the decimal type in the .Net framework to a sql `decimal(29, 4)`. I have seen this behavior in the sql logs from Linq-to-Sql's concurrency checks. The problem is my decimal has a 5 digit precision. In this case Linq to sql is converting `10.55465` to `10.5547` and then throwing a `Row not found or changed` error.

Can I force linq-to-sql to use a custom type mapping for decimal to sql decimal conversions? I'd be perfectly happy with even a `decimal(29,5)` for the concurrency parameter type.

PS: I know I can turn off the update check for all my high precision decimals to prevent the error from happening, but I would prefer to keep the concurrency check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why I was getting this error while attempting to setup a simple example. I'm generating my dbml code, and did not have the dbtype attribute on the column.